# ion3 - What is the key combination to take a print-screen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, ion3

I use ion3 window manager in debian distribution and I was wondering what keys combination I need to use to take a snapshot of my screen to paste it in gimp for instance. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as "windows manager", unless it's a job title at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing, unless ion3 has been extended to do something that isn't the job of a window manager.

You can use an external utility such as import (from imagemagick) to take screenshots and save to a file. You could bind a key in ion3 to run it, of course.

Gimp should also be able to take screenshots for you by itself. Try File/Acquire/Screenshot (or the like, one of the first items).